# Save Photoshop Action Set Automatically

Tags: scripting, automation, action, photoshop

How can I automatically save out action sets in Photoshop via Photoshop scripts (.js/.jsx)?  If that is not possible, is there a way to do it via some other method?

I'm trying to automate the setting up of and saving out of projects for work to the point that all I have to do is click one button to start on a project and then another to submit the completed one so I can do only the work required of me while the redundant stuff is done by the computer.  The only snag I have left preventing this is saving of the custom action sets for each project (these contain project specific transformations on some objects).

Comment: Hmm, apparently there is no known way of doing this... or at least nobody that knows of a way has seen the post yet... Anyone have any idea how this might be done even with a 3rd party app/program?

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X with Automator, it's easy!